# anchor tag not working in mat-toolbar

Tags: html, angular, angular-material2

my anchor tag and button click is disabled in between `<mat-toolbar></mat-toolbar>`. If I place them outside click is working normal. Here is my code, do I have to do anything explicitly to make them work inside mat-toolbar? I tried with ng-href for anchor element which didn't work as well.

```
<mat-toolbar>
    <mat-toolbar-row>
      <div>
          <a href="https://www.w3schools.com">OUR COMPANY</a>
      </div>
    </mat-toolbar-row>
  </mat-toolbar>
```

Comment: It looks okay. By the way, there's no such thing as `ng-href` in Angular, but you can use binding with those square brackets and you define a property in your component file such as so: HTML: `<a [href]="companyURL">Our company</a>` TS: `export class MyComponent { companyURL: 'https://www.w3schools.com'; }`

Answer (score 0):

It works fine !

```
<div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">
   <mat-toolbar>
    <mat-toolbar-row>
      <div>
          <a href="https://www.w3schools.com">OUR COMPANY</a>
      </div>
    </mat-toolbar-row>
  </mat-toolbar>
</div>
```

**[`DEMO STACKBLITZ`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-talrct-nrn6hd?file=app/table-basic-example.html)**